# How to delete almost 1 TB of media from a small Mastodon server hosted at Digital Ocean?

Tags: mastodon

I have a small Mastodon server that's part of the fediverse used by a few people through out the day.

My data storage is a S3 over at Digital Ocean.

This small server with just a few people is quickly coming on to 1 TB of media uploads! There is no way these few guys sharing funny memes can accumulate over 100 GB of media uploads a month!

Is this server just importing content from other instances throughout the fediverse? Is there anyway I can stop it from importing data from users who are not interacting with my instance? How about deleting the aforementioned data not needed from the S3 over at Digital Ocean?

Thank you

I haven't tried anything as I'm not well versed in Mastodon, but was thinking of setting this to true

```
LIMITED_FEDERATION_MODE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also admin on a new instance and I haven't encountered this yet, but have you tried tweaking the time window on the scripts mentioned here?

https://docs.joinmastodon.org/admin/setup/#cleanup